# How to submit email before paypal redirect

Tags: php, jquery, forms, paypal

I have a custom paypal cart and before i get redirected to paypal to buy the items, i want in background to send automatically an email with cart items (item title, address, image link).

This is the paypal form

```
<div id="thebasket">
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr">
...
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="pplbuynowbtn">
</form>
</div>
```

this is is the js

```
    $(theDiv).html(theform).ready(function () {
        $(this).find('input').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var thisitem = $(this).attr("name");
                var thisval = $(this).val();
                $(theDiv).PayPalCart('update', thisitem, thisval);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Now if I press buy now, is going to paypal.com and i can't get his address and the item image from there. This is why I need this email before paypal.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think submitting two forms will be a bad idea.

There are two methods:

**1. AJAX** 
    
Display a submit button that triggers a AJAX call that submits your mail, as the ajax request is completed now trigger the JS function to submit the second form for paypal.

**2. PHP**

You should trigger a PHP script on SUBMIT, which contains:

```
    <?php
    function form()
    {
    //form submitting that sends shipping data
    }

    function paypal()
    {
    //curl script for form posting
    $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $data = array('amount' => '50');

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    var_dump($result);}

    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm beginner with PHP, and I want to use AJAX. I'm writing the code below you if can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Display a fake submit button "Buy Now" that triggers an Ajax call sending the email, then use `$('#thebasker form').submit()` in successful Ajax callback to validate your Paypal form.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I think you should consider giving further explanation about your suggested answer. It would add quality to your post and help keep a high standard on the quality of the site. Keep it up!